# TextView scrollable + onTouchListiner

Tags: android, textview, ontouchlistener, scrollable

I have a `TextView` that is `scrollable`. I've done this through **setMovementMethod(...)**. Now I'd like to add an `OnTouchListener` (setOnTouchListener (...) to handle sideways movements as well, but when I do so, the view is no longer `scrollable`.
**How can I enable both?**

Comment: Please share your code for setOnTouchListener. Are you returning true or false?

Comment: I was returning true. But I changed it to false and now both functionalities are working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably returning **true** on your override of the "**onTouch(View, MotionEvent)**"  method